# simple onclick TypeScript example does not work on JSFiddle

Tags: typescript, jsfiddle

I tried a very basic TypeScript onclick example on JSFiddle.
The example works in JavaScript [Javascript example](http://jsfiddle.net/1c2sqmbo/1/) but does not work under typescript [TypeScript example](http://jsfiddle.net/1c2sqmbo/).

What am I doing wrong in my [TypeScript example](http://jsfiddle.net/1c2sqmbo/)?

HTML

```
<input value="click me" type="button" onclick="myClick()">
```

TypeScript

```
function myClick() {
  alert("myClick")
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong. It seems that TypeScript code does not execute in the global context. If you add `window.myClick = myClick;` then it works as expected.

Comment: Thx for that quickfix - it worked for me. 